# UART Port on the TM4C1294 Board sends garbage

Tags: uart, texas-instruments

I am using the TI TM4C1294XL board's virtual COM port that comes on the ICDI interface. This is the code I am using:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include "inc/tm4c1294ncpdt.h"
#include "driverlib/gpio.h"
#include "driverlib/sysctl.h"

int main(void)
{
    SYSCTL_RCGCUART_R = SYSCTL_RCGCUART_R0;
    while((SYSCTL_PRUART_R & SYSCTL_PRUART_R0) == 0);

    SYSCTL_RCGCGPIO_R = SYSCTL_RCGCGPIO_R0;
    while((SYSCTL_PRGPIO_R & SYSCTL_PRGPIO_R0) == 0);

    GPIO_PORTA_AHB_AFSEL_R = GPIO_PIN_0 | GPIO_PIN_1;
    GPIO_PORTA_AHB_PCTL_R  = 0x11;
    GPIO_PORTA_AHB_DEN_R   = GPIO_PIN_0 | GPIO_PIN_1;

    UART0_CTL_R  &= ~0x1;
    // UART0_LCRH_R &= ~UART_LCRH_FEN;
    UART0_IBRD_R  = 0x30D;
    UART0_FBRD_R  = 0x010;

    UART0_CC_R = 0x0;

    UART0_LCRH_R  = 0x00;
    UART0_LCRH_R |= UART_LCRH_WLEN_8;
    // UART0_LCRH_R |= UART_LCRH_FEN;
    UART0_CTL_R  |= UART_CTL_TXE | UART_CTL_UARTEN;

    while(1)
    {
        while( (UART0_FR_R & 0x0020) != 0);
        UART0_DR_R = 'a';
        SysCtlDelay(1000000);
        // while( (UART0_FR_R & 0x0020) != 0);
        // UART0_DR_R = '\n';
    }
}
```

Here is what I am getting from `putty`:

[image: Putty Session connected to the board]

What is the reason for such garbage characters regardless of what is being sent to the UART port? I tried other UART ports available but with no luck.

Update: For some reason lowering the MCU clock to 12MHz did the trick. Can anyone please elaborate on this and put it as answer? Thank you very much.

Comment: One has to assume you set the right baud rate and framing bit configurations...

Comment: Isn't it that if the baud rate is wrong there won't be anything to display?

Comment: nope.. generally you get garbage back

Comment: @Trevor Please see my update.

Comment: UARTS have specific clocking requirements for each baud rate. Generally the MCU clock needs to be a multiple of the fundamental baud rates to work correctly. If the timing is wrong, there will be a loss of synchronization across the characters and what you decode will appear as garbage.

Comment: Calculation error only becomes a concern when the divisors are in the ballpack.  Often they are calculated at compile time or even runtime from the clock speed in effect and the error will be greater or lesser at different clocks.  But in the code posted, they're simple constants, and may just not be even remotely right for the original clock speed - this is code which assumes a given clock speed (or at least ratio of that to baud) and the assumption may be for 12 MHz.  However it might produce a different valid standard baud rate when clocked at 24 MHz or 6 MHz...